# Trapping right-click in worksheet textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to be able to trap the right-click event when a user right-clicks in a **worksheet textbox** not ActiveX.

I know it can be done easily for userform textboxes, that's not what I'm after.
In the worksheet event `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` I have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    mRightClick.RightClickOnMoMList rngTarget:=Target, boolCancel:=Cancel
End Sub
```

However it doesn't even enter it when I right click on the textbox (but a cell of the same worksheet does work). I suspect that it is due to the `Target` argument being a Range.

Is there a way to make that event trap right clicks on shapes like textboxes as well?

Comment: I think this going to require a `Class` ... I have seen something similar not too long, so its worth searching.

Comment: The worksheet and controls are two different beasts that don't work togeter (at least for events) try to apply your event directly to the control (By changing `Worksheet` by the name of the control in the name of the sub.

Comment: @litelite There is no available declaration of that sort. I've seen it with forms though, I know what you meant.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman What kind of class should I look into? I've never done anything with classes in VBA

Comment: @DavidG - Unfortunately, I can't provide much insight as I have not written too many myself. The basic idea is assign the textbox its on object in the class and pass the actual textbox to that object. Here's a [link](http://www.andypope.info/vba/uf_contextualmenu.htm) you may be able to modify.

Comment: Is this an ActiveX textbox or a "Form Controls" textbox?

Comment: Form controls textbox

Comment: IIR you can't even trap that with the `Application_BeforeRightClick` event, and Shape doesn't source events.  You could probably get it with an API hook, but that seems like a *ton* of effort compared with using the ActiveX control.

Answer (score 2):

I've just done this:
 - opened Excel and entered Design Mode 
 - added a text box to a worksheet 
 - double-clicked the text box, which took me to the Change event for that control 
 - I selected the MouseUp event

What you're after is Button = 2 for the right button (left button is 1).

So...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, _
                            ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                            ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Left-click"
    ElseIf Button = 2 Then
        MsgBox "Right-click"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is event is `BeforeRightClick`, so you should probably intercept `MouseDown` instead.

Comment: Is this an ActiveX textbox?

Comment: Yes, ActiveX textbox